# How do I find my Nexus 7 model number

Tags: cyanogenmod

I am building an adhoc network using Asus Nexus 7. I've managed to root using CyanogenMod and ClockworkMod recovery and establish the adhoc after installing Thinktube image-file. However, i need to buy similar tablets so that i can test the network for real.

I am now trying to find out my Nexus 7 model number. But when i go to ***Settings-->About Tablet-->Model Number***, All I can see is ***Nexus 7***.

how can I find the Model of my Tablet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [XDA Wiki entry of the Nexus 7](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/ASUS_Nexus_7) only mentions two models:

- Wifi Model: ME370T
- Cellular Model: ME370TG

So if you have a functional SIM card slot then you have the cellular Model, otherwise the wifi-only one.

Comment: thanks .. before I wasn't know the difference between ME370T and ME370TG..